# web qr-code scanner usage nimiq qr-scanner github

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, qr-code

I tried to using this qr-scanner https://github.com/nimiq/qr-scanner
which works good but I don't get it to use the reading information. For example it displays me an URL fine but nothing more, cannot click on the displaying link, cannot safe it, cannot use it. Would be fine to get an auto redirect.
Maybe someone can help me to get next steps with this.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For more clearance: https://ibb.co/VL1fc5d just checkout the image, that's what I mean, it detected the code and displays google.com but how can I use this? I would like to make an automatic redirect to this URL when scanned.